# doctype breaks css change function

Tags: php, jquery, css, font-size, doctype

I created a php file that generates a page as follows:

```
{session code}

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Kenshoo Zabbix Console</title>
    <?php
    print $cWeb->getCss($page);
    print $cWeb->getScripts($page,$user);
    ?>

</head>
<body>
...
 <table id="alerts" class="tablesorter" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 </table>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I created a range input that triggers the following function:

```
function adjustFont() {
    $(".tablesorter td").css("font-size", $("#sizeSelector").val());
    $(".tablesorter th").css("font-size", $("#sizeSelector").val());
}
```

Ever since I added the doctype tag, the adjustFont stopped working, removing the doctype returns the functionality but breaks the css.

Any idea what may be causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Does you made it in document on load script? like
`$(function() { your code here });`

Comment: @Michael Why would the doctype affect that?

Comment: Make sure there's no spaces, linebreaks or strange characters before the doctype, and it's generally DOCTYPE, uppercase.

Comment: Do your size selector values have proper units?

Comment: something above DOCTYPE in HTML document is not recommended. why don't you try to put it down below DOCTYPE? and it can be used in lowercase as well because it's case-insensitive, but you may want to use it as uppercase.

Comment: @Barmar I tried both. Odd thing is that when I output the function line to the console and manually type it the font size changes.

Comment: @hina10531 I'm not sure what you mean, but there is no HTML code above the doctype, just php code for the server side.

Comment: as a workaround I removed the default value from the css and had an initial function set the value.

Comment: You've not shown the element with id = sizeSelector, but probably you're missing units on the value. Try `$(".tablesorter td").css("font-size", $("#sizeSelector").val() + "px")`; The spec that describes the variation is http://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-unitless-length-quirk, but it's not easy to follow.